# Does process package from multiprocessing in python executes the processes on multiple cores?

Tags: python, process

I am performing multiprocessing in Python. In Python, there are two classes, Pool and Process, to perform multiprocessing. The class Pool executes the processes on multiple cores depending on the availability of the cores.

I wanted to know whether the Process class executes the processes in parallel on multiple cores or on a single core??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it runs on a different process.

When you instantiate a `Process` object, after calling the method `start()` the current process is going to fork and the new process is going to execute the method `run()`. If you have a system with multiple cores, you might indeed take advantage of this parallelism.

**Note:** the difference between the classes `Pool` and `Process` is that `Pool` spawns multiple worker processes at once, whereas `Process` only spawns a single process; however, both use processes that are distinct from your main process.

Comment: You mean to say that process class will execute the processes on multiples cores if i have a system with multiple cores??

Comment: It will, but it will only spawn one additional process besides your main process. If you need multiple additional processes running at once, you might find it more useful to use the `Pool` class.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. Are you asking if it is possible to spawn multiple processes, one at a time, using the `Process` class? If that's your question, then the answer is yes. You could spawn many identical processes with the class `Process` by using a loop for example. In that case you would end up having multiple processes running in parallel.